# save UDP socket data into file

Tags: file, sockets, datagram

I have a code to send and receive UDP socket

Send UDP code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{

    try
      {
          FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("OUTFILE.txt");
          PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fo);  
          DatagramSocket Socket = new DatagramSocket(4555);
          byte[] receiveData = new byte[1000000];    
          DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

          while(true)
         {  

               receivePacket.setLength(receiveData.length);
               Socket.receive(receivePacket);

                String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());


                System.out.printf("RECEIVED: %s  " , new String(receivePacket.getData()));
                ps.println(sentence);
                ps.println();
                ps.close();
                fo.close();

         }

          File file = new File("OUTFILE.txt");
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
          byte[] fsize = new byte[(int) file.length()];
          int size = fis.read(fsize);
          System.out.println("Received Size = " + size);


      } 
        catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println(e);
        }



}
```

}

I want to write the value of each received data packet into file then get the size of the whole file.
In my code I just got the first received value written in the file.
Could you please tell me how can I write the whole received value in the file.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the first loop, you're closing the streams so additional lines can not be written. You need to move the `ps.close();` and `fs.close()` calls to be outside of the loop. In addition, you have an indefinite loop which guarantees that the code reading from the file can not be called--you need to have some mechanism to determine when to stop looping.

Comment: thank you Nate but it does't work by moving .close() outside the loop.I tried this condition to stop the loop   
                 if (receivePacket.getLength()==0)
                  break;
                
                 but it doesn't stop looping

Comment: That is not a valid way to break the loop. Read the JavaDoc for [`DatagramSocket.receive()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive(java.net.DatagramPacket)): "This method blocks until a datagram is received. The length field of the datagram packet object contains the length of the received message."

Comment: Nate could u plz give me a hint how can I stop the looping??